# validating dropdown list in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation, drop-down-menu

I have a web-form in which there are three drop downs as shown below in the image:

[image]

The form in the above image has 3 drop-down (**Physical persons responsible for operations, Resident, Staff**) and my task is that if nothing is selected it should display a warning message `Please Select an Instrument Type`

The .aspx code which I have used in order to achieve that is:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlInstrumentType2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Label ID="InstrumentTypeSelected" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
<asp:Image class="helpicon" ID="imgSelInst" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/help2.png" ToolTip="imgSelInst"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" InitialValue="---------   Select Instrument Type   ---------" ControlToValidate="ddlInstrumentType2"
   ErrorMessage="Please select an Instrument Type" ValidationGroup="vgrp1">*
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

The above code doesn't seems to validate as it doesn't display any warning message if I don't select anything from the dropdown. I am wondering what mistake I am doing and what changes I need to do in the above code so that it successfully displays warning if I don't select any dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect your `DropDownList` doesn't have `ListItem` item value defined in `InitialValue` attribute, hence you need to use other value to trigger validation:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" InitialValue="0" ControlToValidate="ddlInstrumentType2"
   ErrorMessage="Please select an Instrument Type" ...>*
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

**Note:** Make sure the validation group name defined in `RequiredFieldValidator` exists.

Or in your `DropDownList` (which supposed to be bound for data source) use a `ListItem` with initial value as first item:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlInstrumentType2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="---------   Select Instrument Type   ---------" Value="---------   Select Instrument Type   ---------"></asp:ListItem> 
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Since `RequiredFieldValidator` control only works if `ListItem` is blank, the first approach should be enough.

Comment: I tried using 1st code `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" InitialValue="0" ControlToValidate="ddlInstrumentType2"
   ErrorMessage="Please select an Instrument Type" ValidationGroup="vgrp1">*
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>` but it didn't work for some reasons.